# VLC Plugin without installed the VLC Player

Tags: c#, dll, vlc

I want to use the VLC Plugin on C# without the installation of vlc. It is possible to register the dll for plugin programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ship the library with your application and place it in the same directory, but make sure vlc licence allows you to do so.

Comment: That doesn't work. I copy the whole folder from vlc media and every file in the debug folder.

Comment: okay @Innoszorn - if it's an ActiveX element, you can register it by using the command line `regsvr32 "C:\PathToYourFolder\axvlc.dll"` or start a new process directly from your application

Comment: @Innoszorn - you may also have at look at [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC/) or [this](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet)

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Your solution is nearly perfect. But i think i have to search for another way to program my music an video player, because I have to start the program with administration permissions.

Comment: You just need to run your application as administrator once (when you register the dll). You could do that in the installation process of your application. Don't forget to mark this as the answer, if it helped you, @Innoszorn

Comment: I tried it with a new programm and its a perfect solution. But with my main program, i want to use it is not possible to use this solution. I don't know why. Should i start it before the initialisecomponent procedure in my form or befor i open the form where i want to use the vlc plugin?

Comment: Can someone help how to register with regsvr32 in vb.net please